# Submitting Form once but automatically being doubled / twice on POST method? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working on a project in asp.net(v4.6) mvc(v5), it was working properly on first deployment on the remote server, after the first test trial its giving errors on forms when i submit on **POST** method.
It is automatically posting the form twice which is not required.

**Places i checked for errors:**

1. source code (also DEBUG)
2. searched and tried Logs
3. used tools to check why and from where this issue is occurring (no results)

I fix i found was the browser issue, when i changed from chrome to edge there was no errors... But there is still no notes on what the error is and how it is being generated.

Here is the View.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdmissionCell", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @*Input Fields Here*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Student Record" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CNIC").change(function () {
                $.get("/AdmissionCell/CheckCNIC",
                    { cnic: $("#CNIC").val() },
                    function (data) {
                        if (data === 1) {
                            //alert("Sorry, CNIC already exists, Please enter unique CNIC. or ");
                            //location.reload();
                            var cnicStu = $("#CNIC").val();
                            if (window.confirm('Sorry, CNIC already exists, Please enter unique CNIC or Press "Ok" to goto student details.')) {
                                window.location.href = "/AdmissionCell/Details?cnic=" + cnicStu;
                            };
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.cnic').on('keyup', function () {
                var input = $('.cnic').val();
                if (input.length == 5 || input.length == 13) {
                    $('.cnic').val(input + '-');
                }
            });

            $('.gcnic').on('keyup', function () {
                var input = $('.gcnic').val();
                if (input.length == 5 || input.length == 13) {
                    $('.gcnic').val(input + '-');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: check the handlers bound to form/submit button

Comment: Thank You @MannanBahelim for the answer, can you explain little more so i can understand what exactly i should look for

Comment: Is there click any other click or submit event on button or form?

Comment: No, Only form submits to the corresponding POST method in the controller.

Comment: can you post view.cshtml page ?

Comment: the issue is happening on all pages so there is no point on posting one of them, right?

Comment: Is there any other markup that could be accidentally referencing the page? Script references, image references, css references, all could be mistakenly pointed at '.' or the current page like blank href or balank src

Comment: I think you should check this in _layout page first

Comment: Thankx for the answer, but i have checked the references very carefully, and also checked it now. no issues on references. the problem is there is no issue in edge only the issue is occuring on chrome.

Comment: check for the  favicon.ico file in your project bcz  Chrome by default is looking for a favicon.ico and makes the request for it. it might cause the twice call

Comment: favicon.ico is available and its there at the top of tab

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your jqueryval bundle is included twice.

Once in the view (as shown) and also in your _layout file, so the events are bound twice

Comment: Thankx for the answer, but i have checked the references very carefully, and also checked it now. no issues on references. the problem is there is no issue in edge only the issue is occuring on chrome.